# replace double slash in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm working in a javascript function, in a given string I need to replace `//` for only one slash `/` by now I have:

```
result= mystring.replace("\/\/", "/");
```

bt it's not working, I still get the string with double slash, so which is the proper regex to indicate the double slash to the replace function?

I already tried:

- !//!
- ////
- ///g///g

**Edit:**
I'm using it to correct a URL that is saved in the string, for example,
sometimes that URL can be something like: `mywebpage/someparameter//someotherparameter` and that double slash gives problem, so I need to replace it to one single slash like: `mywebpage/someparameter/someotherparameter`

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]: Show how you define `mystring`. Show how you test the value of `result`.

Comment: why are you escaping it in a string?

Comment: "which is the proper regex" — Why are you asking about regex when you are using a string and not a regex?

Comment: _"it's not working"_ Cannot reproduce

Comment: @Quentin you're right, so how should it be? `res.replace(/\/\//, "/");` ??

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova Can you include text of `mystring` and  expected result of `result` at Question?

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova — The replace method accepts a string as the first argument. What it "should" be depends on what the problem is. The code does what you say it should do so it isn't clear what the problem is.

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova — Re edit: Don't just *describe* the strings, provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin Good point. The `RegExp` at Question should return expected result, unless the `RegExp` is replacing `//` following protocol at URL, instead of at `//someotherparameter`. `mystring = "http://mywebpage/someparameter//someotherparameter";
result= mystring.replace("\/\/", "/");console.log(result)`

Comment: Given the data added to the question: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/jiyohim/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova How do you get the original string?

Comment: Related: [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use regex `/\/\//`(or `/\/{2}/`) with a global modifier to replace all occurrence.

```
result= mystring.replace(/\/\//g, "/");
```

```js
console.log(
  'hi// hello//123//'.replace(/\/\//g, '/')
)
```

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova : glad to help :)

Comment: Take into account  that the regex is not a string. I mean, `"/\/\//g"` does not work

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to escape it if it is a string used as a replacement

```
console.log("asd//qwe".replace("//","/"));
```

If it were a regular expression, you would need to escape it

```
console.log("asd//qwe".replace(/\/\//,"/"));
```

Now if there is more than one set, than you need to use a regular expression with a global modifier.

```
console.log("asd//qwe".replace(/\/\//g,"/"));
```